# How can I connect QButtton array?

Tags: qt5, qtablewidget, qpushbutton

I'm Korean, so Please understand that I'm not good at English.

I just make POS System with Qt5.

I want to make when I push of some button(red), display on table(yellow);

like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNo5z.png)

so, I read some files that have some name of item and put them in QPushButton array.

and I connect that QPushButton array like this :

```
void qt_test::put_item(QWidget *Widget, QString location){
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout();
QPushButton *button[25]; //set QPushButton array;
QString name[25];  //store name of item;

fileio file;
file.file_io2(name, location);  //read file and get name of item;

int temp=0;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<6;j++,temp++){
       //insert name in QPushButton
        button[temp] = new QPushButton(name[temp]);  
        button[temp]->setMinimumSize(10,70);
        layout->addWidget(button[temp],i,j);
    }
}

Widget->setLayout(layout);

//connect QPushArray.
connect(*button,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(input_item()));
```

}

and this is the slot that i thought

```
void qt_test::input_item(){
    if(!(P_ROW==9)){
        ui.sel_item_table->item(P_ROW,0)->setText("test");
        ++P_ROW;
    }
```

the problem is,

1. I have no idea how could I put the text that in QPushBotton in the QTable.
2. How Can I Control buttons that I connect in my slot.
   In my code, only one button works... not all buttons.
   just onion soup ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect each individual push button:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    for(int j=1;j<6;j++,temp++){
       //insert name in QPushButton
        button[temp] = new QPushButton(name[temp]);  
        button[temp]->setMinimumSize(10,70);
        layout->addWidget(button[temp],i,j);

        connect( button[temp], &QPushButton::clicked, [=] { input_item( button[temp] ); } );   
    }
}

...

void qt_test::input_item( QPushButton* button )
{
    ui.sel_item_table->item(P_ROW,0)->setText( button->text() );
}
```